# Как прогнать кадры с камеры через нейросеть?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, opencv, qthread

Как сделать "прогон" кадров с веб камеры (функция `camera_on`, 
а также `control_timer`) через нейросеть (функция `network`)?

```
class PredictNumber:
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')

    def network(self, image_video):
        ret, frame = image_video.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        plaques = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(plaques):
            roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            r = 400.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
            dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
            resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            w_resized = resized.shape[0]
            h_resized = resized.shape[1]
            frame[100:100 + w_resized, 100:100 + h_resized] = resized
        return resized
```

```
    def camera_on(self):
        ret, image = self.cap.read()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        img = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        image_video = PredictNumber.network(self, img) 
# Таким образом не работает, 
происходит вылет программы.
        self.ui.Cam.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image_video))
        self.ui.Cam.setScaledContents(True)

    def control_timer(self):
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
            self.timer.start(0)
```

**UPD**: Переписал и вынес в отдельный класс камеру

Чтобы не париться с переводом форматов из cv в QT `image` сделал вот так, добавил каскад, однако все равно происходит вылет программы:

```py
class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')
    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:
                image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                flipped_image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
                with_cascade = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(flipped_image, 1.3, 7)
                for (x, y, w, h) in with_cascade:
                    roi_color = ret[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    r = 300.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
                    dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
                    resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                convert_to_qt_format = QImage(resized.data, resized.shape[1], fresized.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(convert_to_qt_format)
```

Здесь происходит инициализация класса, а также его запуск по нажатии кнопки.

```
        self.Worker1 = Worker1()
        self.Worker1.ImageUpdate.connect(self.image_update_slot)
        self.ui.Camera_btn.clicked.connect(self.Worker1.start)
```

А это уже слот для обновления камеры. Последняя строчка делает размер камеры в соответствии с виджетом

```
    def image_update_slot(self, Image):
        self.ui.Cam.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))
        self.ui.Cam.setScaledContents(True)
```

Comment: Ваше обновление обнадеживает. Добавьте немного больше кода. Покажите как вы  создаете экземпляр класса `Worker1` и все строки где используется имя этого экземпляра. А также покажите где находится слот, который принимает `convert_to_qt_format` из дополнительного потока и  что вы написали в этом методе.

Comment: Кода добавил, каждую часть расписал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить класс `Worker1`:

```
class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__()
        self.ThreadActive = True
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)    
    
    def run(self):
        while self.ThreadActive:
# --------> vvvvvvvvvvvv
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')
            ret, frame = self.cam.read()                      # Capture.read()
            if ret:
                image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                flipped_image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
# ---------------------------> ???????????                
#                with_cascade = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(flipped_image, 1.3, 7)
# ---------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv                 
                with_cascade = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(flipped_image, 1.3, 7)
                
                for (x, y, w, h) in with_cascade:
                    roi_color = ret[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    r = 300.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
                    dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
                    resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                convert_to_qt_format = QImage(resized.data, resized.shape[1], fresized.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(convert_to_qt_format)
```

Comment: Действительно, спасибо огромное, дело оказалось в доступе к самому каскаду) Что уже только не перепробовал.

Comment: @Parcurcik пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что не работает - передаете данные типа `QImage`, а обрабатываете как `VideoCapture` (?)

Надо сделать что-то типа такого:

```
class PredictNumber:
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')

    def network(self, image):
        # QImage в cv::Mat  
        frame = Mat(image.height(), image.width(), <тип данных из cv, который соответствует QImage.Format_RGB888>...)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        plaques = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(plaques):
            roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            r = 400.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
            dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
            resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            w_resized = resized.shape[0]
            h_resized = resized.shape[1]
            frame[100:100 + w_resized, 100:100 + h_resized] = resized
        return resized
```

Если не получится `Mat(image....)`, по попробовать как написано вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886924/4711135)

Comment: Поправил, однако выбрасывает из приложения все равно при включении камеры

Comment: @Parcurcik незнаю, нужно смотреть, отлаживать.